# Macro to split weight into columns Request

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Let's say I have a column of numbers in A2 going down, to a random number, such as:

```
0.50
1.00
1.00
1.10
1.10
```

And I wanted a macro to split them into Major and Minor basically.. Anything before the Period, I want moved over to Column B. Anything after the Period I would like moved to Column C, and the . Just removed completely.

So

```
   B  C
   0  50
   1  00
   1  00
   1  10
   1  10
```

Like that, Pretty simple. I don't know enough about Excel VBA to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Just record the following macro:

1. Copy column A to B
2. Format column B as text
3. Data->TextToColumn on Column B with separator "."

Answer (score 1):

I would just use formulas instead of VBA. Put this in B2:

```
=INT(A2)
```

and this in C2:

```
=(A2-B2)*100
```

Then copy and paste down.